# Sql injection problem to retrieve tables from a database

Tags: sql-injection

Hello why when search of test the vulnerability of a website i receive this kind of error '' it seem information_schema table does not exist! trying to guess tables! total tables_found 0'' But the Db information_schema exist and too the other Database.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  There's not enough info to answer your question.  You should give more info on the current vulnerability and the tool you're using.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .

Comment: I have try to retrieve the tables with Havij automatic tool i have try too with sqlmap but with havij i have more result with other dbs so the error that i receive is with havij.